# Pulling power off a battery stack at different voltages

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power, batteries, embedded

If I'm powering a device with a series-connected stack of rechargeable batteries, can I pull different voltages at different points and route them to different components?  I need to run a 12V solenoid, an Arduino (6V-12V recommended), some stepper motors (around 5 or 6V), and possibly a servo (though that can probably come straight off the Arduino).

If I have, for example, four 3V cells, can I grab 6V from two of them and 12V from all four at the same time, or will that do bad things to the cells' relative charge?  Space and complexity are constraints here, so adding a regulator might be possible but would make things more complicated.

Alternatively, would using higher-capacity cells adding up to 6V and a boost converter to get the 12V work?  I'd be concerned about current, but my fears might be baseless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scheme of tapping off the batteries at different points will work.  However nothing is for free.  The batteries used in both the 6V circuit (let's call them Bat1) and the 12V circuit (call them Bat2) will see more power drain than the two used for just the 12V circuit.

The problem arises when you want to recharge them in series.  Bat2 which will have more energy than Bat1 will raise the voltage of Bat1 + Bat2 faster than normal.  Often this causes the charger to back off the current, which ends up leaving Bat1 undercharged.  They cycle can worsen over multiple uses leaving Bat1 either undercharged or overcharging Bat2.

This is why most electronics derive the power they need from the batteries keeping the charge and discharge paths identical.

You could choose either to boost the 6V or regulate the 12V.  Typically the decision is made by which circuit needs the most power delivered to it.  In your example if the motors take 2x more current than the rest of the design, then it would make sense to optimize the delivery of the supply to the motors.  If everything is about equal, then it comes down to looking at the cost/efficiency of linear regulation (less EMI and simpler) versus boosting it (noisier and more components).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll probably go with the regulator to ensure a smooth output; my only concern would be getting a lot of power dissipation in a linear regulator.  Do you think a switching regulator would be feasible?

Comment: @Trebawa In cases with large voltage drops or larger power draws then switching regulators are more than feasible, they are required.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep in mind that the cells shared by all the loads will discharge faster than the ones that are only used by some of the loads. They're supplying current to all the loads, after all. Other than that, as long as you keep your circuit commons straight, you should be fine. Your boost converter idea should also work, but will drain an equivalent 6V cell more quickly than that same cell in series with another. After all, all the energy would be coming out of one battery instead of two.